# Layout for a family tree

Tags: graph, gephi, graph-visualization

I have a dataset of DNA relationships (as a percent match) between myself and few hundred relatives, almost all distant relatives. I also have data on DNA relationships between each of them and certain other members in the dataset.

I'm hoping to build a network graph that shows the interrelationships and have Gephi build something that loosely resembles a family tree. But even using a small sample database I can't get the resulting graph to look anything like that.

I want each relationship (i.e. edge) to have a "force" related to the closeness of the relationship, so distant relatives (nodes) are pushed further away. I want the graph to self-assemble based on these "forces" and assume there is a layout for this, but I haven't found one.

I'm currently putting the DNA relationship in the `weight` column, and not using the `interval` column at all. But even using just 8 relatives and artificially perfect data I have to manually move nodes around to make it look remotely useful.

What layout should I use for this type of graph, and what other advice can you offer to make this work?  Should the `weight` field increase or decrease as relationship distance increases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> … and have Gephi build something that loosely resembles a family tree. But even using a small sample database I can't get the resulting graph to look anything like that.

A family tree connects descendants (mostly). DNA similarity (as a percentage) does not conform to this structure. Related questions [may be answered here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dna?sort=votes).

Setting a `Library` > `Edges` > `Edge Weight` -filter to the DNA similarity attribute may help (but will not produce "*something that loosely resembles a family tree*").

> I want each relationship (i.e. edge) to have a "force" related to the closeness of the relationship, so distant relatives (nodes) are pushed further away. I want the graph to self-assemble based on these "forces" …

All layouts work like that. However, Gephi does not feature [hierarchical](https://github.com/gephi/gexf/wiki/Advanced-Concepts) positioning. 3rd party candidates include [EventGraphLayout](https://gephi.org/plugins/#/plugin/eventgraphlayout), [Layered Layout](https://gephi.org/plugins/#/plugin/layered-layout) and [Concentric Layout](https://gephi.org/plugins/#/plugin/concentric-layout).

> Should the weight field increase or decrease as relationship distance increases?

The greater an edge's weight, the stronger its connection (resulting in less distance between the nodes it connects). To a family tree however this is irrelevant.

> I'm hoping to build a network graph that shows the interrelationships between each member …

> What layout should I use for this type of graph, and what other advice can you offer to make this work?

Following steps emphasize [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient) and [modularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_(networks)):

1. Calculate modularity.

   [image]
2. Color nodes by modularity class:
    `Appearance` > `Nodes` > `Partition` > `Modularity Class`
3. Apply a layout; `ForceAtlas 2` for example (with `Dissuade Hubs`, `LinLog mode` and `Prevent Overlap` enabled).

Apply the `Contraction` layout afterwards if necessary. Optionally set node size according to (for example) `Eigenvector Centrality` (prior to applying layout).